# Anyone know a WYSIWYG editor with Hex color picker

Tags: wysiwyg

I am looking for a WYSIWYG editor for EE2 that allows you to drop in a hex color. Any got any ideas?

I looked at Wygwam, Editor and Expresso but none of them seem to have any color control. Any thoughts?

Comment: What do you need the hex colour for? If it's to change text colour or background WYGWAM (aka CKeditor) already has that functionality.

Comment: I just discovered it - its exactly what I need. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

Wygwam does the trick and allows you to add a hex code. 
https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/wygwam